# Best data type for my array/collection

Tags: c#, arrays, collections

I would like to store a enum value and a number in a collection or array, with the ability to update a specific value.  Any recommendations on best method, taken into account performance impact?

E.g.

```
enum Colour {Red, Yellow, Green};
```

Would like to store (and update):

Red: 230

Yellow: 500

Green: 50

Comment: Maybe `Dictionary<Colour,int>` , I think it's best for keeping key->value :)

Comment: With only 3 values: use the concept which implementation is easiest.

Comment: instead of this , you can add value to your enums. for example you can add value 230 to your red enum item and after that you can read the value of it.

Comment: @pooyan He wants to be able to edit it.

Comment: I found this article, and from this is seems like Dictionary might be the best performing one: http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/06/16/c.net-fundamentals-choosing-the-right-collection-class.aspx

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance yes you are right . i didn't see that . :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Dictionary<Colour, int>`:

```
Dictionary<Colour, int> dict = new Dictionary<Colour, int>();
dict[Colour.Red] = 230;
dict[Colour.Yellow] = 500;
dict[Colour.Green] = 50;
Console.WriteLine(dict[Colour.Red]) //outputs 230
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use a dictionary:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<Colour, int>()

dictionary[Colour.Red] = 230;
dictionary[Colour.Yellow] = 500;
dictionary[Colour.Green] = 50;
```

Doing this, every colour exists at maximum once in the collection. If you're using a `Collection` or an `Array`, you'll be able to have multiple times the same colour in the collection.